# Cannot install latest stable nodejs after node 6 was installed

Tags: nodejs

I tried to upgrade node 6.x to latest stable. I tried few methods with apt-get, nvm, npm and nothing helped.

Why I cannot get latest stable node on Ubuntu 16.04 as simple as:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

How can I get latest stable node on Ubuntu 16.04?

here my terminal copy-paste:

```
pm@pm-node:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]     
Hit:3 http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Get:4 http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]    
Hit:5 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease              
Get:6 http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]  
Hit:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Hit:8 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_8.x xenial InRelease                     
Get:9 http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [317 kB]
Get:10 http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [226 kB]
Get:12 http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [190 kB]
Get:13 http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [266 kB]
Get:14 http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5 888 B]
Get:15 http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3 328 B]
Get:16 http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 Packages [7 084 B]
Get:17 http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe i386 Packages [7 060 B]
Get:18 http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [4 696 B]
Fetched 1 334 kB in 2s (535 kB/s)                                              
Reading package lists... Done
pm@pm-node:~$ sudo apt-get install nodejs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nodejs
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 173 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/12,7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 61,3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package nodejs.
(Reading database ... 221467 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nodejs_8.10.0-1nodesource1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nodejs (8.10.0-1nodesource1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up nodejs (8.10.0-1nodesource1) ...
pm@pm-node:~$ node -version
bash: /home/pm/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.4/bin/node: No such file or directory
pm@pm-node:~$ node --version
bash: /home/pm/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.4/bin/node: No such file or directory
pm@pm-node:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
```

The PPA will be added. After this install.

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

To check your version try this `nodejs -v`.

You should see an output like: `v8.10.0`

You may want this too:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Best of luck.

---

I've just tried my instructions on debian raspberry pi and result is:

```
pi@192:/ $ nodejs -v
v8.10.0
pi@192:/ $ npm -v
5.6.0
```

Comment: I was able to get node 8.x installed this way, but not the npm. Could you explain why I need python-software-properties to setup node?

Comment: Over the internet I've read that some people are having issues installing nodejs without this. It makes no sense to me but just to be sure.

Comment: Yes, same experience :) - no sense to me either.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays you can use the supported Debian repositories at https://github.com/nodesource/distributions

> NodeSource will maintain Ubuntu distributions in active support by Canonical, including LTS and the intermediate releases.

They provide instructions for each Node version you might want, e.g.

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_19.x | sudo -E bash - &&\
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

There are instructions for Debian/Ubuntu, RedHat and others, as well as custom steps if you wish to avoid running arbitrary commands from the internet.

This is roughly the same as the `deadsnakes` repositories used by Python, but for Node.